# JavaのクラスをKotlinで継承し，特定のメソッドだけOverrideしたい

Tags: android, java, kotlin

あるJavaのクラスをKotlinで継承し，他のメソッドに影響を与えないように１つのメソッドだけOverrideしたいのですがエラーが出て困っています．

元のJavaのクラスでは`private String`と表現されているフィールドが，継承したKotlinのクラスでは`final val`と解釈されており，メソッド内で`set`が出来ないと言った状態です．

Java:

```
public class J {
    private String a;
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    void m() {
        a = "hello";
    }
    void m2() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
open class K(): J() {
    override fun m() {
        a = "helloK" // "Val cannot be reassigned"
    }
}
```

Comment: `protected String`が正しいのでは。

Comment: 元にしているJavaのライブラリのソースを見る限り，privateと書いてあります

Comment: そもそも`private`なフィールドは、Javaで継承しても参照することはできません。Kotlin側で見えている`a`は、Java側のgetterである`getA()`がKotlin側にread-onlyプロパティとして継承されたものでしょう。元のJavaクラスがご質問中にあるような構成であれば、例示されたようなことはKotlinであろうとJavaであろうと実現できない、と言うことになると思いますが。

Comment: そうだったのですね．ではReflectionでいくことにします．